# how to get the string data in HTML tags using regex

Tags: java, regex

```
<p><a href=\"https://news.yahoo.com/during-siege-orlando-gunman-told-police-islamic-soldier-034552865.html\"><img src=\"https://s1.yimg.com/bt/api/res/1.2/1aLfwfzLVx7.osxsV87uog--/YXBwaWQ9eW5ld3NfbGVnbztmaT1maWxsO2g9ODY7cT03NTt3PTEzMA--/http://media.zenfs.com/en_us/News/Reuters/2016-06-20T125326Z_1_LYNXNPEC5J0TN_RTROPTP_2_FLORIDA-SHOOTING.JPG\" width=\"130\" height=\"86\" alt=\"***A woman mourns as she sits on the ground and takes part in a vigil for the Pulse night club victims following last week&#039;s shooting in Orlando\" align=\"left\" title=\"**A woman mourns as she sits on the ground and takes part in a vigil for the Pulse night club victims following last week&#039;s shooting in Orlando***\"** border=\"0\" /></a>The Florida nightclub killer called himself an &quot;Islamic soldier&quot; and threatened to strap hostages into explosive vests in calls with police during the three-hour siege, according to transcripts released by the FBI on Monday. In a first call he made to a 911 emergency operator, Mateen said &quot;I pledge allegiance to Abu Bakr al-Baghdadi, may God protect him, on behalf of the Islamic State,&quot; referring to the head of Islamic State. The FBI and U.S. State Department released partial transcripts of the four calls with the emergency operator and crisis negotiators earlier on Monday, omitting the shooter&#039;s references to the leader of Islamic State, saying they did not want to provide a platform for propaganda.</p><br clear=\"all\"/>
```

For the above HTML tag by using regex I am eliminating HTML tags and getting only description about news. In that descripton i.e., **"A woman mourns as she sits on the ground and takes part in a vigil for the Pulse night club victims following last week's shooting in Orlando "** this quoted part is missing. How to get that data also ?

This is the regex i am using to get description

```
String news_description = item_obj.getString("description");

String news_description_noHTMLString = news_description.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
```

Can anyone suggest me how to get that ?

Answer (score 0):

Not prefect solution, but will work in most cases.

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(alt|title).*?\"(.*?)\"");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(news);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.printf("%s: %s\n",m.group(1), m.group(2));
    }
```

To be more perfect you should apply pattern only to tags interior not a whole text.

Comment: Thank you.. though its not perfect solution worked for me @krzydyn

Answer (score 0):

Uses regex to capture HTML text is not a good idea because HTML syntax can be complex with inline `CSS` and `JAVASCRIPT`. So you have to write more complex regex. Best way it uses a HTML parser (https://jsoup.org/) that in JAVA.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<tag1><tag2>text</tag1></tag2>");    
String ownText = doc.body().ownText();
String text = doc.body().text();    
System.out.println(ownText);
System.out.println(text);
```

But if you really need to uses regex and if your HTML format is fixed you can uses this regex to capture the text between `</a>` and `</p>`:

```
.*<\/a>(.*)<\/p>
```

Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/yN8wJ9/1

Comment: I would not recommend using [your regex](https://regex101.com/r/yN8wJ9/2).

Comment: thnank you Nayana for your reply.